# read text from file containing escape characters to compile time equivalent

Tags: java, properties, text-parsing

I would like to parse a text file or a java property which contains text such as:
"test\n123\t456"
to the equivalent if it were written in 
String test = "test\n123\t456";

i.e. I want the bytes to be the same when the text is read from a file compared to compiled in  a java class.

I hope this makes sense,

-- Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Commons have [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: Unfortunately this library seems to unescape too much when not wanted. An input of "test\\\n123" returns "test\n" instead of "test\\n" (or ignoring completely). I might need to use my own solution similar to what Peter mentioned.

Comment: it works properly. there's actually double unescaping happens: in string literal and in unescapeJava. if you pass "test\\\\\\n123" (which is actually 'test\\\n123' when unescaped in literal) you will get expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my IDE, if I paste into the middle of a string it turns tabs into \t and newlines into \n for you.  I suggest you try that.

For example, if I paste

```
test
123
456
```

into a string it becomes

```
"test\n" +
"123\n" +
"456"
```

Comment: I am looking for some code snippet which converts something like: "test\n" to "test(special new char line here)". i.e. the source code version would be: "test\\n" and changed to the source code version: "test\n"

Comment: do you mean something like text.replace("\\n","\n");

Comment: sort of, but I would like an easy way to cover all possible special characters